# Get canvas position of image in A-frame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, aframe

Right now, I have an A-frame scene with a 360 video mapped onto the inside of a sphere, and I added a few `<a-plane>`'s, but I wanted to add 2D buttons on the canvas (using plain ol' HTML) next to the `<a-plane>` (kind of hovering on top of the object). The problem is that the user can click and drag the `<a-plane>`, so the position in 3D environment will change (and so will the size of the `<a-plane>` since the image will get warped when you rotate the screen).

Is there any way to find out the x-y position of the bounds of the image in the `<a-plane>` in the canvas element? I have to use the canvas because the  is slightly warped when it's at the corner of the screen due to the skewed perspective.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mouse-cursor component that will start a raycaster based on the XY of the mouse. So you can tell when the actual mouse cursor hovers over an object: https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component

For the raw three.js example, check out https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes